# Creating Button in Flash CC

Tags: flash, createjs

I am trying to create an interective button using HTML canvas document in Flash CC. I simply want the button to show different colors on mouse press, release and hover.   Thanks

Comment: Can you please post the code you already wrote and tell us what error you get?

Comment: Have a look at the ButtonHelper class: http://www.createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/ButtonHelper.html -- There is a ButtonHelper demo in GitHub as well. https://github.com/CreateJS/EaselJS/blob/master/examples/ButtonHelper.html

Comment: Thanks everyone for response. @ Lanny2 , I have followed the Button Helper Class, still it not working, Can you please create a simple button as per my requirement and share the code or working link.

Thanks